# How to build Memgraph for ARM on Debian?

Tags: docker, debian, cross-compiling, memgraphdb

I want to build Memgraph for ARM on Debian. I see that the [documentation has been revamped](https://memgraph.com/docs/) and that there is a whole new section about [installing using Docker](https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/docker) but I can't find info on building in docs or in [repo](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a document called [Memgraph Internals](https://memgraph.notion.site/Memgraph-Internals-12b69132d67a417898972927d6870bd2).

The whole process is explained under [QuickStart](https://memgraph.notion.site/Quick-Start-82a99a85e62a4e3d89f6a9fb6d35626d). Memgraph build for specific operating system is based on [toolchain archives](https://memgraph.notion.site/memgraph/Memgraph-Internals-12b69132d67a417898972927d6870bd2).

When it comes to ARM we have direct support for Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 but it's possible to extend / build a new toolchain for any Linux + ARM combination.

Disclaimer: I work at Memgraph.